# socket.emit in listenerfunction does it work?

Tags: javascript, flask, socket.io, real-time

heroes

I've got a question. I'm doing simple chatApp as a project to pass a subject and i do struggle on emitting disconnected message to main room by user fallowing unload function(). My question is does it work correctly the code like this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.returnValue = ' ';
});

window.addEventListener("unload", ev => {
    socket.emit('disconnected', {
                                    "username": "USER-1",
                                    "sessionID": "SESSION123456789TRY"
                                });
});
```

Or you can not use function like emit on that specific event which is unload. Would be great to get an expert info. All Greetings

Comment: Hi @Sunni, you actually doesn't need to fire a `disconnected` event cause socket is already firing an event when user disconnected. Maybe use that instead? :)

Comment: Hey @Sunni, I couldn't read it from here maybe you can also edit post itself? :)

Comment: Hello, @Halil Çakar thanks for your response. Yeah, but i'm emitting separated socket 'disconnected' on this example object(later i'll put a DATA into it) to the backend-side server(Technology flask) which in this case listener for that socket
`@socketio.on('disconnected')`


  `def disconnected(data):


    username = data["username"]
  

    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  

    print(username)
  

    emit("disconected-feedback", {...DATA...  
                                    
})`  
Which bolded listener should listen to that specific event on javaScript-side

Comment: Well i actually have an example of a chat-app here https://github.com/halilcakar/private-chat/ maybe you can check from there? It also uses beforeunload event. https://github.com/halilcakar/private-chat/blob/master/public/js/index.js#L44